# Distribute Shapes vertically within a Parent Shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

The figure below draws a simplified depiction of a bijection and works so far but there's definitely room for improvement. For example

```
 \draw [blue-node] (-2,2.5) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a1) {$a_1$};
```

sets a node for the text and not the circle shape which causes the arrow to intersect with the circle's outline slightly; I couldn't figure out how to mark each element (`a1,a2,...`) with a variable while also drawing the circles such that they are vertically distributed evenly within the `parent` set which is the main reason why I used hard coded coordinates for the circles to place them. I would love to hear suggestions how I could work around both these issues better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{blue-node}=[color=blue!75,fill=blue!20,thick]
        \tikzstyle{red-node}=[color=red!75,fill=red!20,thick]
        \tikzstyle{parent}=[color=black!75,fill=black!5,very thick]
        \tikzstyle{mapsto}=[->,very thick]
        % set A
        \draw [parent] (-2,0) ellipse (1cm and 4cm);       
        \draw [blue-node] (-2,2.5) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a1) {$a_1$};        
        \draw [blue-node] (-2,1.25) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a2) {$a_2$};
        \draw [blue-node] (-2,0) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a3) {$a_3$};
        \draw [blue-node] (-2,-1.25) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a4) {$a_4$};
        \draw [blue-node] (-2,-2.5) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (a5) {$a_5$} (-2,-5) node[anchor=south,color=black] {$A$};
        % set B
        \draw [parent] (4,0) ellipse (1cm and 4cm);
        \draw [red-node] (4,2.5) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (b1) {$b_1$};
        \draw [red-node] (4,1.25) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (b2) {$b_2$};
        \draw [red-node] (4,0) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (b3) {$b_3$};
        \draw [red-node] (4,-1.25) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (b4) {$b_4$};
        \draw [red-node] (4,-2.5) circle (0.4cm) node[anchor=center] (b5) {$b_5$} (4,-5) node[anchor=south,color=black] {$B$};
        % mapsto
        \draw [mapsto] (a1) -- (b1);
        \draw [mapsto] (a2) -- (b5);
        \draw [mapsto] (a3) -- (b3);
        \draw [mapsto] (a4) -- (b4);
        \draw [mapsto] (a5) -- (b2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{sketch-bijective-function}
    \caption{Example of an bijective function}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to show than explain.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, minimum width=0.8cm] (a1) {$a_1$};
\draw[red] (a1.north east) -- (a1.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot with my first question!